# How to allow allow ipv6 on nginx centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos, ipv6

I am not able to access my ipv6 like so
http://[2605:3030:2020:1310:d838:efff:fe29:1964]

for ipv4 I can do this

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Do I need to spcify these rules for ipv6 too? I am using nginx centos 7

my server config:

```
server {

        listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name    example.com www.example.com;
        root           /var/www/example.com;
        index          index.html index.html index.php;

}
```

When I netstat nginx it outputs:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15499/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15499/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      15499/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      15499/nginx: master
```

However I can't access the ipv6 with my browser, the website doesnt load at all.

Comment: firewalld affects both IPv4 and IPv6. If you actually want help with this, you will need to tell us exactly what the problem is. You also should use the real IPv6 address, not a fake one.

Comment: You have still put fake information in your post. The IPv6 address is fake and the domain name is fake. This will probably require the real information. ([Why we ask for real information?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632))